# Connect to local Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio with QGIS

Tags: qgis, sql-server

I am running SQL Server 2014 Management Studio and 2.18.16 version of QGIS. When I attempt Layer -> Add Layer -> SQL Server layer and click new:

- Connection name: Local
- Provider/DSN blank
- Host: Localhost

Clicking "List Databases" shows a - "Server does not exist or access denied" error that disappears really fast. Other processes I am using can connect to the database fine (although this had an option for Windows Authentication). I have also tried enabling TCP/IP and named pipes in the management studio options

Comment: Management Studio is a client, just like QGIS. You want to connect to the Server, not the Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the settings in the services did fix it, I just neglected to restart the service!